# Using DICT.get(key) but still getting KeyError in Django

Tags: django, keyerror

A bit of background info about the project I'm doing. It's an automatic essay checking system and the admin user should be able to add, edit, and attempt questions in the system. I'm able to add essays to the system but was not able to edit and attempt. Whenever I try to edit and attempt, KeyError appears.

I'm not sure what went wrong because I recreated the system using my professor's code and his worked.

Here is the KeyError message for edit and attempt question:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qvJs.png

And here is the code for views.py (its quite long):
http://pastebin.com/88vvZJ6J

I've read a lot of solutions on Stack Overflow regarding KeyError but none of them seem to help except for this which comes close to my problem: [Getting KeyError in my django code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28729109/getting-keyerror-in-my-django-code).

According to users from that post, he was able to solve the KeyError by changing some lines. And a lot of users mention about using DICT.get(key) but it seems to me that my current code (views.py) is already using the DICT method? (Please correct me if I'm wrong!)

Comment: here you go: http://pastebin.com/W7MYAQGP

Comment: We prefer textual information to be presented as text here, in the question. So, would you copy the text of the error you received, and add it as a formatted block of code in the question itself? Please also do the same for the Python code. You'll be unlikely to fit all that code into the question, so you'll need to cut it down to the smallest possible code sample that reproduces this error. This helps us guard against future broken links. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Oh okay thanks for your help! I realised my stupid mistake...

Previously I booted up the django system using this command which uses port 8000

`python manage.py runserver`

Should have used port 8080 instead

`python manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8080`